# I making Restaurant app form Udemy tutorial it show me this error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I facing this error

```bash
Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.
tabs_screen.dart:34
```

- `Object` is from `dart:core`.
- `Widget` is from `package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart`

```bash
('/C:/flutter_windows_3.3.4-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
framework.dart:1

body: _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'].
```

---

#### Code

```dart
class TapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TapScreen> createState() => _TapScreenState();
}

List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
  {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Catergories'},
  {'page': FavoitesScreen(), 'title': 'your Favorites'}
];

class _TapScreenState extends State<TapScreen> {
  int _selectPageIndex = 0;
  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("meal"),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
        currentIndex: _selectPageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart `Object` can be anything and the body of the scaffold expects only the type `Widget` thus causing the error. It is always better to use `Widget` type annotation.

In your case, Check if that `Object` is a widget type or not

```dart
 _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'] is Widget ?  _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'] as Widget : Text("Page not found");
```

#### Full code

```dart
class TapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TapScreen> createState() => _TapScreenState();
}

List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
  {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Catergories'},
  {'page': FavoitesScreen(), 'title': 'your Favorites'}
];

class _TapScreenState extends State<TapScreen> {
  int _selectPageIndex = 0;
  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("meal"),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'] is Widget ? _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'] as Widget : Text("Page not found"), // Change here
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
        currentIndex: _selectPageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide default widget on null case.

```dart
body: _pages[_selectPageIndex]['page'] as Widget? ?? Text("not found"),
```